# Is there any open source tools for RPA (Robotic Process Automation)

Tags: automation, ui-automation

We want to build a [RPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotic_Process_Automation) software.

The definition of RPA: A software 'robot' is a software application that replicates the actions of a human being interacting with the user interface of a computer system.

I searched RPA open-source software several days.

Is there any open-source tools for RPA? I know some commercial software like "BluePrism", "OpenSpan", etc.

Thanks for your advise.

Comment: Workfusion is a free rpa tool. Just take a look

Comment: Robot Framework - http://robotframework.org/rpa/

Answer (score 17):

Not quite open source, but free nonetheless. UiPath are also a player in the RPA space, and they have a community edition for individuals/non-profits etc...
http://www.uipath.com/community

You can also use Python to build your own automation apps. I'm currently looking at this:
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/

Comment: UIPath would have been my first comment, but I also think that WorkFusion is now offering (or is planning) its platform with a community version

Comment: WorkFusion is not open to download at this moment.

Comment: Well, if you take the definition of RPA from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481233/whats-the-technical-difference-between-robotic-process-automation-rpa-and-tes?s=2|1.6099
just take a free test automation tool (e.g. selenium) and add a machine learning lib, plus a few more libs for OCR and stuff, you can are close to a open source RPA stack.

Comment: WorkFusion now offers free enterprise-grade software called [RPA Express](https://www.workfusion.com/rpaexpress)

Comment: I have been developing a completely free *and* open source RPA tool: https://github.com/saucepleez/taskt

Answer (score 1):

NO.. Till date there are no open-source RPA tool..

Comment: There's one now called Roro hosted in [github](https://github.com/arviedelgado/Roro)

Comment: Workfusion RPAExpress is a free tool in the market. One needs to register with business email on this link (https://www.workfusion.com/rpaexpress) and gets a download link in the registered email.

Comment: @Stuti Verma Free != Open Source.  I have been developing a completely open source RPA tool called taskt https://github.com/saucepleez/taskt

Comment: Robot Framework can be used as RPA framework - http://robotframework.org/rpa/

Comment: TagUI (https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI) It's opensource and maintained by AI Singapore (https://www.aisingapore.org/)